# Apache Solr 3.5 - 4.0 HunspellStemFilter returns another values than Hunspell in console / command line with same dictionaries

Tags: apache, solr, spell-checking, full-text-search, hunspell

When I used HunspellStemFilter for stemming the czech language text, it returns me bad results.

For example word "praha" returns "praha" and "prahnout", what is not correct.

So I try the same in my console (Hunspell command line) with exactly same dictionaries and it returns only "praha" and this is correct.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It sounds like a bug, probably better to fill in a Jira issue